# Hazlecast eviction is not working with USED_HEAP_SIZE with Hazlecast 5.0

Tags: hazelcast

I'm having below map configuration for Hazlecast

```java
private MapConfig initializeDefaultMapConfig(int ttlMinutes,int size) {
    MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
    EvictionConfig evictionConfig = new EvictionConfig();
    evictionConfig.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU);
    evictionConfig.setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE);
    evictionConfig.setSize(size);
    mapConfig.setBackupCount(0);
    mapConfig.setEvictionConfig(evictionConfig);
    mapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(ttlMinutes);
    mapConfig.setMaxIdleSeconds(ttlMinutes);
    return mapConfig;   
}
```

I am running Hazlecast in single node instance only. It still exceeds the specified memory size. Please suggest.

Comment: What parameters do you pass for `int ttlMinutes,int size` ? How many entries do you insert ? What size are the keys ? What size are the values ?

Comment: Any updates on this ? The snippet posted doesn't go wrong for me, so the problem is probably demonstrated by the rest of the code. A [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be ideal. These generally don't need more than 20-30 lines, and make it much easier to establish the issue. For example here, backup count (probably) is irrelevant to the problem on a 1-node cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related, this issue in Hazelcast could be the explanation.

See [Github issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/19862)